# Stanford Word Segmenter for Chinese in Python how to return results without punctuation

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, punctuation, chinese-locale

I am trying to segment a Chinese sentence with the Stanford Word Segmenter in Python, but currently the results has punctuation marks in it.  I want to return results without the punctuations, only the words.  What is the best way to do that?  I tried Googling for an answer, but didn't find anything.

Comment: An example would be better.

Comment: @AvinashRaj no problem.  Here it is the code: intxt = '我很好，你呢？'


chinese_postagger = POSTagger('models/chinese-nodistsim.tagger', 'stanford-postagger.jar', encoding='utf-8')

segmenter = StanfordSegmenter(path_to_jar="stanford-segmenter-3.5.1.jar",
path_to_sihan_corpora_dict="./data", path_to_model="./data/pku.gz", path_to_dict="./data/dict-chris6.ser.gz")

print segmenter.segment(intxt.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: The output is "我 很 好 ， 你 呢 ？", but I want it to be "我 很 好 你 呢 "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd be better off just removing the punctuation after the text has been segmented; I'm fairly sure the Stanford segmenter takes cues from punctuation in doing its job, so you wouldn't want to do so beforehand. The following works for me on UTF-8 text. For Chinese punctuation, use the Zhon library with regex:

```
import zhon.hanzi
import re
h_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % zhon.hanzi.punctuation)
intxt = # segmented text with punctuation
outtxt = h_regex.sub('', intxt)
```

And depending on the text you're working with, you may also need to remove non-Chinese punctuation:

```
import string
p_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
outtext2 = p_regex.sub('', outtxt)
```

Then you should be golden.

Comment: Thank you so much, but this didn't work for me.  Here is the code that I tried, please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: import zhon.hanzi
import re
import string




h_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % zhon.hanzi.punctuation)
intxt = '我很好，你呢？'
outtxt = h_regex.sub('', intxt)
print outtxt
p_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
outtext2 = p_regex.sub('', outtxt)
print outtext2

Comment: the output are always 我很好，你呢？

Comment: Your code works for me if I specify the string as unicode, with a u:         intxt = u'我很好，你呢？'

Comment: Wow! That's awesome!  Thank you so much.  I am going to now try to give it a line in a file to see how well it works.  Again, thank you so much!